# How to block CSS and js file loading in Google Blogger template?

Tags: javascript, html, css, blogger

I want to block some CSS and js file loading in my Blogger, like

```
<link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='//www.blogger.com/static/v1/widgets/1937454905-widget_css_bundle.css' />
```

And

```
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//www.blogger.com/static/v1/widgets/4127629733-widgets.js"></script>`
```

, but I can't find these tags in Blogger template, it's added by Blogger.Is there a way to remove or comment these tags?

Comment: Why do you keep screwing up the post that I fixed! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use at your own risk. :)

[How to remove Blogger CSS, Reset Stylesheet](http://damzaky.blogspot.com/2012/10/how-to-remove-blogger-css-reset.html)

This is actually a method to override the CSS provided by the Blogger template. There is no way to remove it, and transversely, there is no way to remove the JavaScript either.

Comment: Nice use of the word transversely.

Answer (score 0):

Its Ok to remove Blogger CSS that you can add your own CSS. But if you want to remove Blogger JavaScript then it will stop function your Widgets but you can also do this if you want to use Blogger as simple HTML page.

Here I am sharing both is simple steps...

- [**How To Remove/Hide Blogger Official CSS In Your Custom Template?**](http://www.exeideas.com/2013/06/how-to-hide-blogger-official-css.html)
- [**How To Remove/Hide Blogger Official Widgets JS In Your Custom
  Template?**](http://www.exeideas.com/2013/06/how-to-hide-blogger-official-javascript.html)

Answer (score 0):

Make a backup of your template first.

**TO BLOCK BLOGGER CSS:**

Find this:

```
<b:skin><![CDATA[lots-of-css-code]]></b:skin>
```

and replace with this:

```
&lt;style type=&quot;text/css&quot;&gt;&lt;!-- /*<b:skin>*/</b:skin>
```

Find this:

```
 <b:template-skin>bunch of code</b:template-skin>
```

and replace with this:

```
<link href='https://www.somewhere.com/yourstylesheet.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'/>
```

or replace with this:

```
 <style>your-custom-css-here</style>
```

**TO BLOCK REMOVE ALL BLOGGER JAVASCRIPT AND WIDGETS:**

Find this:

```
<b:include data='blog' name='all-head-content'/>
```

and replace it with this:

```
<meta content='blogger' name='generator'/><link expr:href='data:blog.url' rel='icon' type='image/x-icon'/><link expr:href='data:blog.url' rel='canonical'/><data:blog.feedLinks/><b:if cond='data:blog.url == data:blog.homepageUrl'><link href='http://www.blogger.com/openid-server.g' rel='openid.server'/><link expr:href='data:blog.url' rel='openid.delegate'/></b:if>
```

Find this:

```
</head>
```

and replace with this:

```
&lt;!--</head>--&gt;&lt;/head&gt;
```